# Copy row, and dependent rows in another table, and dependent rows in another, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with an 'id' column, and other various columns.  Each row of data will has a unique 'id'.  This 'id' is referred to in another table, which also has rows with unique 'id'.  Each of these is referred to in yet another table.

We'll call the tables 'items', 'item_options', and 'sub_options'.  I'm wanting to copy one row in 'items', and also copy everything linked to it's id in 'item_options' and everything in 'sub_options' that is linked to the id's in 'item_options'.

For example:

Say in 'items' the columns are 'id' and 'title'.
In 'item_options' the columns are 'id', 'itemID', and 'option'.
In 'sub_options' the columns are 'id', 'item_optionsID' and 'subOption'.

I can get this far:

```
insert into dbo.items (title)
  select title
  from dbo.items where id = '123'
```

From here, I've been returning the new id's for the newly copied rows in 'itmes' then using server side language to loop through and copy the 'item_options' and then loop through those to copy 'sub_options', but I'm hitting the db very often and the performance is taking a hit.

I'm wanting to do the whole thing in SQL, but I can't seem to figure it out.

For sample data, I'll try this:

**dbo.items**
id: '123'
title: 'New Car'

**dbo.item_options**
id: '456'
itemID: '123'
option: 'Custom Wheels'

id: '457'
itemID: '123'
option: 'Custom Paint'

**dbo.sub_options**
id: '789'
item_optionsID: '456'
subOption: 'Chrome'

id: '790'
item_optionsID: '456'
subOption: '20 inch'

id: '791'
item_optionsID: '457'
subOption: 'Red'

Basically, I want to copy all of this, while making the id's match all of the newly generated id's while making the copy.

Comment: The actual schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the expected result with that sample data would make this a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @Phill you need to clarify your question, are you inserting a new item and then inserting its related options into item_options and sub_options ? or are you talking about items that already existed in items table and you need to insert options and sub options for these items ? both are different cases with different solutions. (if there is a sample data would be much better).

Comment: @iSR5 - added sample data and explanation above, thanks.

Comment: @Phil thanks for the sample and explanation, check my answer see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the new 'id' values as you insert into each table to use them for the foreign key references in the child tables. The most reliable way to capture the new 'id's is using the SQL [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as that will always give the correct ids and can handle multiple ids (many of the other approaches to obtaining the newly created record id have pitfalls worth avoiding).

You also want to wrap it in a transaction to ensure its an all or nothing operation (you may also want additional error handling).

Because the `output` clause on an `insert` statement doesn't allow values from the original table I've used a `merge` statement for the second part, with a match condition of `1=0` i.e. it will never match and therefore always insert, and the `merge` statement does allow values from the original table in the `output` clause.

```
declare @Id int = 123;

declare @ItemOutput table (IdNew int);
declare @ItemOptionOutput table (IdNew int, IdOld int);

begin tran;

insert into dbo.items (title)
  output Inserted.id into @ItemOutput
  select title
  from dbo.items I
  where I.id = @Id;

MERGE INTO dbo.item_options as [Target]
USING (select id, [Option], (select IdNew from @ItemOutput) from dbo.item_options) AS [Source] (id, [Option], IdNew)
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (itemID, [Option])
  VALUES ([Source].IdNew, [Source].[Option])
  OUTPUT Inserted.id, [Source].id
  INTO @ItemOptionOutput (IdNew, IdOld);

insert into dbo.sub_options (item_optionsID, subOption)
  select (select O.IdNew from @ItemOptionOutput O where O.IdOld = SO.ID), SubOption
  from dbo.sub_options SO
  where SO.id in (select O.id from dbo.item_options O where O.ItemID = @Id);

commit;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give this a shot and I'll let you know.

Comment: This is getting close, however, in the second insert set on the third line, O.id gives "The multi-part identifier 'O.id' could not be bound"

Comment: @Phil - sorry I forgot that the the `output` clause doesn't allow original table values for an `insert` (and there were a couple of other syntax errors). Try now.

Comment: I'm just getting to this today, thanks for the updated code, I'll report back as soon as possible.

Comment: The Merge statement worked well.  I had to add a condition `WHEN NOT MATCHED AND [Source].itemID = @Id THEN` and that did it for me.  I'm now implementing this into the actual database which has many more columns and many more tables.  I'm pretty positive this will greatly enhance the performance, thanks!

Comment: Great - please edit my answer with your changes so that it is a fully working answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED (After OP Clarifications) :**

You're trying to insert a new row in table `items`, and you need to save the new generated id (AKA IDENTITY) for that row to be used as FK in other insert operation (in your case you want to use it in item_options).

if the id in `items` and `item_options` are Identities, then you can make use of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

**SCOPE_IDENTITY()**

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope

[Learn More ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

So, your insert will be as simple as this :

```
INSERT INTO dbo.items (title) VALUES ('New Car')

INSERT INTO item_options (itemId, [option]) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'Custom Wheels')

INSERT INTO sub_options (item_optionsId, subOption) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'Chrome')
```

the first `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will take the last generated id in items, and the second one will take item_options id, and so on.

you can also store the id in a variable to be used further like this :

```
DECLARE 
    @itemId INT 
,   @optionId INT


INSERT INTO dbo.items (title) VALUES ('New Car')

SELECT @itemId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO item_options (itemId, [option]) VALUES (@itemId, 'Custom Wheels')

SELECT @optionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO sub_options (item_optionsId, subOption) VALUES (@optionId, 'Chrome')
```

this will give you more flexibility using the ids out of its scope.

I hope this will solve your dilemma.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I know OP needs to copy them, using join with INSERT would do that without the need of doing all that work, unless if the current schema requires more work than it should, that's we don't know, and needs to be clarified from the op if needed.

Comment: @DaleBurrell wait a minute, does this mean the op trying to add an item, and then adding its related options into other tables ? so we're talking about new inserted items and not an existing ones ? (guessed that from your answer).

Comment: @DaleBurrell probably better to wait for the clarification from the OP, I've already asked OP on the comments. ;) ..

Comment: That doesn't handle an variable number of options per item and a variable number of SubOptions per option though.

Comment: @DaleBurrell If you meant that he could be inserting multiple options and suboptions per item, then this could be solved by using a temp table or a table variable to store them accordingly.  OR better yet, inserting everything in one table, and then distribute them into their tables.

Comment: According to his sample date he *is* inserting multiple options and suboptions per item. Which means `scope_identity()` doesn't work for him unless you suggest inserting them one at a time.

Comment: @iSR5 Thanks, I'm going to try this out and I'll let you know.